# Multiple routers with vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am running a PHP application where I will need some pages to have the ability to completely swap out views. I need a fully fledged router because I need to take advantage of the history mode API.

It is easy enough to do something like this with the Vue router:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        { path: '/', component: DefaultView },
        { path: '/map', component: MapView }
    ]
});
```

Within PHP I simply load the router like so and pass the PHP generated backend data to both views:

```
<router-view data="<?= $data ?>"></router-view>
```

This works for one page, but what if I want to have another page with a completely different set of routes? The router needs to be made aware what page it is on in order to differentiate between different sets of routes.

I either would need to check the URL of pass in a prop like I am already doing with my data. I am unsure how to read the prop data from the router though.

What would be a good way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

you simply make two named `router-views`

and pass different data to these router-views.

```
<router-view class="view one"></router-view> //default
<router-view class="view two" name="a"></router-view>
<router-view class="view three" name="b"></router-view>

routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      components: {
        default: Foo,
        a: Bar,
        b: Baz
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/map',
      components: {
        default: Foo2,
        a: Bar2,
        b: Baz2
      }
    }
  ]
```

Or use nested route views //children

```
routes: [
        { path: '/page1', component: page1,
          children: [
        {

          path: 'route1',
          component: route1
        },
        {

          path: 'route2',
          component: route2
        }
      ]

       },
        { path: '/page2', component: page2, ... }
    ]
```

Comment: These can't be independently navigated though? Say you have two sections of a page and you want to navigate independently in them (each section is routed independently of the other), this isn't something that can happen here?

Comment: Proposed solution does not actually show two routers.